# Ubuntu Software Center, Update and pretty much everything else doesn't work :D

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, software-center

The Software Center closes instantly after I opened it. `sudo apt-get update` and all commands related to this don't work either.

```
E: Typ »!DOCTYPE« in line 1 of sources list /etc/apt/sources.list.d>/medibuntu.list is unknown.
E: The sources list could not be read.
```

Sorry that its German but language selection doesn't work as well.
It seems like the lists can't be opened :(

Comment: Did you manually edit `sources.list.d`?

Comment: no :(, I didn't do anything

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 , no modifications

Comment: Which country??

Comment: germany :D but why does the country even matter?

Comment: @dufte please correct your command to `sudo apt edit-sources`

Comment: Because I was about to generate a optimal `sources.list.d` for you :D

Comment: please execute `sudo apt edit-sources`, copy the content of the file and paste it to your original post/question. As others as well i assume you have a broken sources.list. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete the `medibuntu.list` file, since the medibuntu repositories are no longer supported or maintained, [and are now obsolete](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu).

You can do so by typing

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
```

In a terminal. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Ok I did so, and it didn't show any error

Comment: It worked, medibuntu.list doesnt existent any more